# Reformatting JSON message from a CSV file

Tags: python, json, csv

I am currently working with Python and have not much experience with this code. I am using VScode and am trying to reformat data from a CSV file into a new CSV file. I have the following data and was wondering how I can reformat it since one column is a JSON message and the other two columns are a unique sensor ID and timestamp. Ideally I want to make a separate column for each sensor ID with all parameters from the JSON message as columns.

I also want to have this output into a new CSV with separate columns for each data type in the JSON message. Current code below:

```
with open(file name here) as file:
reader = csv.reader(file)
for row in reader:
    if row[1] == 'sensor/200187000000000000000000/501':
        print (row[2])    

data = (r'file name', 'r')
df = pd.read_json(data, orient='index')
print
```

I thought `pd_read_json` would convert the message into separate columns for me but I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'tuple'>
```

Here is a sample of the dataset in text format:

```
receivedTS,topic,messageData
1623887376046,sensor/200187000000000000000000/501,"{""m1"":0,""m2"":0,""t1"":222,""t2"":232,""t3"":230,""t4"":200,""timestamp"":1623887386}"
1623887070457,sensor/200187000000000000000000/501,"{""m1"":0,""m2"":0,""t1"":222,""t2"":232,""t3"":232,""t4"":205,""timestamp"":1623887079}"
1623887062762,transceiver/004900314E46500D2033334D/event/ex/scan,"{""sensors"":[{""id"":""200187000000000000000000"",""type"":""501"",""modAdr"":3,""fw"":""48.50"",""hw"":""15.15""}],""timestamp"":1623887071}"
1623887056853,transceiver/004900314E46500D2033334D/data/network,"{""c"":1,""d"":0,""n"":[""53001""]}"
1623887051515,transceiver/004900314E46500D2033334D/data/cell-strength,"{""rssi"":-61,""ber"":3,""timestamp"":1623887028}"
1623887045991,transceiver/004900314E46500D2033334D/data/mains-voltage,"{""mv"":24288,""timestamp"":1623886996}"
1623887040884,transceiver/004900314E46500D2033334D/data/battery-voltage,"{""mv"":13648,""timestamp"":1623886996}"
1623887030393,transceiver/004900314E46500D2033334D/event/boot,"{""rebootReason"":""0"",""version"":""17.501"",""mBoard"":""0.0.4"",""expBoard"":""0.0.7"",""sBoard"":""0.0.6"",""timestamp"":1623886993,""sensors"":[]}"
1623887017480,transceiver/004900314E46500D2033334D/event/netid,"{""imsi"":""204047116508564"",""imei"":""352909081612471""}"
1623886957737,transceiver/004900314E46500D2033334D/data/mains-voltage,"{""mv"":24280,""timestamp"":1623886908}"
```

Expected output columns of new file:

sensor ID, Timestamp, m1, m2, t1, t2, t3, t4

Hope this is enough information.

Comment: You forgot the word `open` in `data = (r'file name', 'r')`.  Further, if that's the same file as above, then you can't just read the whole file as JSON.  You will need the `csv reader` again, and you can pass row[2] to `json.loads`.  I'm not sure why you have pandas in there at all.  Also, are you sure those fields are `[1]` and `[2]`, and not `[0]` and `[1]`?

Comment: If you include the contents of the original csv (as text) and the expected contents of the new csv that you want (as text), I can help you code it out. You shouldn't post images here as it is hard to copy-paste it if someone wants to help you.

Comment: @Joshua I have done this for you hope there is enough information there

Comment: @tripleee Sorry about that, this is my first time posting.

Comment: thanks @TimRoberts, I have managed to pass json.loads in and get the data for m1, t1 etc. values for each individual sensor. I am now wondering how to output these to a new CSV? To my understanding json.load stores the values as a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hopefully simple and obvious enough attempt.

```py
with open(csvfilename) as infile, open(newcsv, 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    keys = ['sensor ID', 'timestamp', 'm1', 'm2', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4']
    writer.writerow(keys)
    for row in reader:
        if not row[1].startswith('sensor/'):
            continue
        jdata = json.loads(row[2])
        jdata['sensor ID'] = row[1][7:]
        writer.writerow(jdata[key] for key in keys)
```

The main heureka moment here is probably the final line, which pulls out the requested fields from `keys` in that particular order from the JSON dictionary.  On the previous line, we add the sensor ID into the extracted dictionary so that the subsequent code can be made really simple.

I have assumed that you want the `sensor/` lines only, with that prefix removed (that's what the `[7:]` does) and that the timestamp should be the one from the JSON data, not from the similarly formatted `receivedTS` field in the input CSV. (Going forward, probably try to be more specific about such details.)

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly, in addition to this, how would I add a grouping module for different sensor IDs?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by grouping; if simply sorting the output is insufficient, maybe post a new question with proper details (example input, desired output, and a [mre]).

Comment: I am unable to upvote due to still being a beginner. The problem is still present I am unable to group the output for different sensor ID's

Comment: There's nothing about that in your question, and I vaguely remember I had to figure out what you actually seemed to want by reading between the lines already for this answer. Probably ask a new question with more details because I don't think you can convey what you want in comments here. See also [How to ask.](/help/how-to-ask)